# Post on facebook user Pages using Facebook Grpah API PHP

Tags: php

I have scenario  which I want to discuss with stackoverflow users that it is possible or not.

Scenario:
Suppose I have a facebook user unique Id and its page Id.Can I post On his pages using facebook Graph API or not. The user is not friend of mine.

If it is possible. Please provide me some sugggestions.

Comment: Have you tired something? There are API functions for that but you have to have an app with the right permissions to do that.

Comment: yes you can..you have to create a `canvas application on facebook` and that user should `login to your application on facebook`.. than and than you can achieve this...

Comment: Thank you all for your reply. Yes, it is possible.

Comment: You can _not_ post to other people’s walls, only to the wall of the current user of your app.

Comment: yes we can post on other's user wall if he is our friend with the help of Feed Dialog Box. But in my question I am talking about post on user's facebook page.